# how to merge multiple row of text into one ID using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I have a dataframe similar to this

```
ID  text
A    name;job
A    like;interest
A    speak;too
B    talk;info
B    study;rule
C    study study 
C    learn learn
```

I want to mix all text together under one unique ID

```
ID     text
A    name;job,like;interest, speak;too
B    talk;info, study;rule
C    study study, learn learn
```

For seperater, it can either be comma or [].

my code currently look like this

```
df.groupby('ID')['text'].agg('sum')
```

Is there anyway to work on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `groupby` with `agg` and a aggregating function:

```
df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).agg(','.join)
```

Output:

```
  ID                              text
0  A  name;job,like;interest,speak;too
1  B              talk;info,study;rule
2  C           study study,learn learn
```

Or as a list:

```
df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).agg(list)
```

Output:

```
  ID                                  text
0  A  [name;job, like;interest, speak;too]
1  B               [talk;info, study;rule]
2  C            [study study, learn learn]
```